# Square matrix with complex entries whose space of eigenvectors have dimension $1$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

Let $A\in M(n,\mathbb C)$ be a matrix such that the space of eigenvectors have dimension $1$. Hence $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue (because distinct eigenvalues give rise to linearly independent eigenvectors) , call it $\lambda$.

How to show that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $(X-\lambda)^n$ ?

I can clearly see that the Characteristic polynomial is 
$(X-\lambda)^n$ hence the minimal polynomial is $(X-\lambda)^m$ for some $m\le n$ , but I can't exactly show $m=n$. I am really looking for a solution without using Jordan blocks.

Please help.

Comment: A related question here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350271/prove-that-dimnai-i-if-a-is-nilpotent

Comment: @orangeskid: that answers my question ... thanks

Comment: @Louis:  You are very welcome!  With just a bit more work, we can prove the general Jordan canonical form result in a similar way.

Comment: @quasi: in the answer not accepted in the linked question, it is shown that $n_{j+1}-n_j \le n_j - n_{j-1}$ holds forall $j\ge 0$ from which it follows $n_{n-1}\le n-1$ which is what want (here $n_j=\dim \ker (A^j)$ )

Comment: @Louis: Yes, I follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the unique eigenvalue of $A$, and let $B=A-\lambda I$.

We know $B^n=0$.

Let $m$ be the least positive integer such that $B^m=0$.

Our goal is to show $m=n$.

By hypothesis, we have $\text{ker}(B)=\langle{v}\rangle$, for some $v\ne 0$.

For each positive integer $k$, let $d_k=\dim(\text{ker}(B^k))$.

**Claim:**$\;d_{k+1}\le d_k+1$ for all $k$.

**Proof:**

Suppose $x,y\in \text{ker}(B^{k+1}){\,\setminus\,}\text{ker}(B^k)$.

Then $B^kx,B^ky\in\text{ker}(B)$ and $B^kx,B^ky\ne 0$ (since $x,y\not\in\text{ker}(B^k)$), hence $B^kx=sv$ and $B^ky=tv$ for some nonzero scalars $s,t$.

Then $B^k(tx-sy)=tB^kx-sB^ky=t(sv)-s(tv)=0$, hence $tx-sy\in\text{ker}(B^k)$.

It follows that $x,y$ are linearly dependent mod $\text{ker}(B^k)$, hence $d_{k+1}\le d_k+1$, as claimed.

Noting that $d_1=1$ and applying the claim, it follows that $d_m\le m$.

But from $B^m=0$, we get $d_m=n$, hence $m=n$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Your argument does go on to show in general that $\dim \ker(A^{j+k})/\ker (A^j) \le \dim \ker (A^k)$ i.e. $\dim \ker(A^{j+k}) \le \dim \ker (A^j) + \dim \ker (A^k), \forall j,k\ge 0$